# No output to the file

Tags: c++

A practice question on **C++ Primer**:

> write a program that takes the names of an input file and two output files. The input file should hold integers. Using an *istream_iterator* read the input file. Using *ostream_iterator*s, write the odd numbers into the first output file. Each value should be followed by a space. Write even numbers into the second file. Each of these values should be placed on a separate line.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 4)
        return -1;

    ifstream ifs(argv[1]);
    ofstream ofs_odd(argv[2]), ofs_even(argv[3]);

    istream_iterator<int> in(ifs), in_eof;
    ostream_iterator<int> odd_iter(ofs_odd, " "), even_iter(ofs_even, "\n");

    for_each(in, in_eof,
        [&odd_iter, &even_iter](const int i)->void {*(i & 0x1 ? odd_iter : even_iter)++ = i; });
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that, under the directory of program compilation, the expected results can be obtained, but if the program and file are copied to the root directory, it returns -1.

What is wrong with the code?Can someone tell me where the problem is?

Comment: You are not checking if the `ifstream` and `ofstream`s are successful in opening the files. Depending on platform and permissions, a user of your program may or may not have write access to the root directory of a drive.

Comment: User of program have write access to the root directory of a drive.

Comment: How to check whether the *ifstream* and *ofstreams* are successful open?

Comment: Is there anyway you can lookup about [`ifstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream),  since my eyesight is blurring because a long day?

Comment: @gaofeng Just check `if(ifs)` and `if(ofs)` before.